# SCONS: Run target always, not only if updated

Tags: c++, scons

Based on [SCONS run target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766450/scons-run-target) I created a basic SCONS script to build and then run my unit tests:

```
test = env.Program(
    target='artifacts/unittest',
    source= sources + tests
)

Alias(
    'test',
    test,
    test[0].abspath
)
```

After I modified the code, this works great:

```
> scons test
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ [...]
[Lots of compiler output]
unittest.exe
===============================================================================
All tests passed (22 assertions in 4 test cases)
```

If I run scons test now again without changing the code, it sees no need for building again, which is correct, but also doesn't run the tests again:

```
> scons test
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `test' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

But, obviously, I want the tests to be run even if they are not rebuilt:

```
> scons test
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `test' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
unittest.exe
===============================================================================
All tests passed (22 assertions in 4 test cases)
```

Is what would be the easiest way wo get this result?

Comment: Just an aside, but _"But, obviously, I want the tests to be run even if they are not rebuilt"_ ... is really **not** obvious. Why would the result ever change unless the code does?

Comment: At least for me this was a obvious use case, sorry if I thought this applies also for other while it doesn't.
Two examples, valid for me:
 - a test doesn't only rely on the code, but also on a external file that is read by a test executable, e.g. csv. During CI, this file comes from version control and is asumed to be constand, but during local development I might change it without changing the code.
 - I simple closed my terminal window and want to re-run the tests after opening it again to re-check the results.

Comment: You still have the unit test executable, so can always run it directly in the second case. This is hopefully uncommon enough that I'd prefer to do something manual than to have all unit tests run every time for no reason. In the other case, if the data file is a dependency, you should tell your build system about it, and then it can work normally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it now by Creating a PseudoBuilder using AddMethod to concat a Builder and a Command:

```
env.AddMethod(
    lambda env, target, source:
        [
            env.Program(
                target=target,
                source=source
            )[0],
            env.Command(
                target,
                source,
                '.\\$TARGET'
            )[0]
        ]
    ,
    'BuildAndRun'
)

env.Alias(
    'test',
    env.BuildAndRun(
        target='artifacts/unittest',
        source= sources + tests
    )
)
```

Works as expected so far:

```
> scons test
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ [...]
[Lots of compiler output]
.\artifacts\unittest
===============================================================================
All tests passed (22 assertions in 4 test cases)
> scons test
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
.\artifacts\unittest
===============================================================================
All tests passed (22 assertions in 4 test cases)
```

Only drawback: the backslash in the command makes me windows-dependent.

Any Opinions?

Comment: You shouldn't need the Lambda at all. You can just list those two items in your Alias.  Your solution looks over complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
env.Pseudo('test')
```

That should mark the target as not generating any files, and may work for you.

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to pseudobuilders, I would be interested in your opinion on my solution.

Comment: Pseudo() is NOT related to pseudobuilders.  It marks the target as a "false" target and so scons won't expect/care about the target file being created.  Did you try the above?

Answer (score 0):

Have also seen `AlwaysBuild` used to trigger unit test execution.  "Seen it" doesn't mean it's best practice necessarily (@bdbaddog is the expert here!).